# *ngfor split data of an array

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I consume a external JSON API with this array.

```
temperature_mean: [ 16.94,19.9,19.13,15.22,15.52,15.62,12.47 ],
```

I want to split this array into seperated objects with an *ngFor loop:

```
<div class="card">
<h2>Temperature</h2>
 <div *ngFor="let temp of cityTemperature">
      {{cityTemperature}}
 </div>
</div>
```

That's what I got back:

[image]

But I want on each line only one object. How can I do that and seperate this loop?

Comment: change {{cityTemperature}} to {{temp}}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your html to:

```
<div class="card">
    <h2>Temperature</h2>
     <div *ngFor="let temp of cityTemperature">
          {{ temp }}
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your help. was unable to see the forest for the trees :)